# Can a believer talk to Allah in Paradise about anything he wishes and any time he wishes?

Tags: allah, sunni, jannah, blessings-of-allah

I know that in worldly life, a believer cannot talk with Allah except through a prophet or messenger He sends to people, but what saddens me is that the Era of Prophets is closed permanently and now there is no way I can ask Allah questions about any matter based on this verse which Allah said:

> "And it is not for any human being that Allah should speak to him except by revelation or from behind a partition or that He sends a messenger to reveal, by His permission, what He wills. Indeed, He is Most High and Wise." ([**Quran, 42:51**](https://quran.com/42/51))

But, I don't know if there is a verse in which it says that a believer can talk with Allah in Paradise without any intermediate just like Moses. Or at least to be a strong, reliable and authentic narration which tells that a believer can talk with his Lord in Paradise about anything and any time he wishes.

Questions which I want to ask Allah directly are:

1. Oh Allah! Is it 100% that Transylvania truly belonged to Romania and never truly belonged to Hungary even though it was under occupation for some time?
2. Oh Allah! Is it 100% true that I as a Romanian am truly the descendant of Romans and Dacians? Just to have a confirmation only.
3. Oh Allah! Will You Create another 7 Universes after You destroyed the actual 7 Universes? And will You Create a new and countless civilizations around the 7 Universes after the destruction of these Universes and after the end of Judgment Day? Or we are first and last of Your creation?

The main reason I want to ask these questions, is because I want to have a confirmation to see which one is correct, Hungary or Romania regarding Transylvania. And also, someone said that the dacians were eradicated by Romans because they were a threat to Romans and I wanted to know the absolute truth about dacians, I want to know if they were eradicated or not.

**NOTE:** Could someone please answer my question? I would be really happy and grateful if you would do this. Because, honestly I tried to find the answer for this question but I didn't find anywhere, maybe I didn't know how to look for it. Could someone please bring me 100 authentic, reliable and strong narration which says if a believer can talk with Allah in Paradise as much as he likes and about anything and of course, any time he wishes? I really need some help in this matter.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

عن عدي بن حاتم  قال: قال رسول الله ﷺ: ما منكم من أحد إلا سيكلمه ربه ليس بينه وبينه ترجمان، فينظر أيمن منه فلا يرى إلا ما قدم، وينظر أشأم منه فلا يرى إلا ما قدم، وينظر بين يديه فلا يرى إلا النار تلقاء وجهه، فاتقوا النار ولو بشق تمرة

this hadith in albhari's book  its an  reliable and authentic narration the mean of it 
(None of you but God will speak to him, there is no translation between him and him)
in this hadith Prophet Mohammed said that every one of us(the believer ) will talk to the god directly 
and in quran there is verse in sura75-aya22-23 the god say(The faces of that day are fresh*To her Lord, looking) 
the answer is yes the believer  will see there god and talk to him directly 
i will give you some link to read this hadith in Arabic because i don't know any page that talk about Islam in English 
https://khaledalsabt.com/explanations/1540/%D8%AD%D8%AF%D9%8A%D8%AB-%D9%85%D8%A7-%D9%85%D9%86%D9%83%D9%85-%D9%85%D9%86-%D8%A7%D8%AD%D8%AF-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7-%D8%B3%D9%8A%D9%83%D9%84%D9%85%D9%87-%D8%B1%D8%A8%D9%87

Comment: https://sunnah.com/bukhari/81/128

Comment: Could you please quote reports from Prophet and some verses from Quran? Because, I forgot Arabic and now I don't know how to read the classic Arabic

Comment: You'd better stick on official translations than translate in your own words especially when it comes to qur'an and hadith.